# Nested FLET block inside LET block (and vice-versa)

Tags: nested, lisp, let

Is it considered idiomatic or non-idiomatic to have a `LET` block nested inside a`FLET`/`LABELS` block ?

Again, I may be coming at this all wrong, but I'm trying to mimic the generic `where` block in Haskell (so I have a `defun` and I want to write code that uses certain temporary bindings for values and functions.

In case these are non-idiomatic (after all, I shouldn't expect to transfer over usage from one language to another), what's the right way to do this ?

E.g. something like (stupid example follows ...)

```
(defun f (x) (
  (let* ((x 4)
         (y (1+ x))
         (flet ((g (x) (+ 2 x)))
            (g y))))
```

Comment: You have some parentheses errors; also, function parameter `x` is not used.

Comment: I suppose that since you said "idiomatic", this could be answered somewhat objectively by surveying existing code, and seeing how often this occurs, but even then, you'd have to decide which code is idiomatic, and which isn't.  As such, I think this is probably a bit too subjective.  That said, there's nothing the matter with flet inside let, or let inside flet.  If you're trying to emulate Haskell structures, I wouldn't worry about writing idiomatic code so much though;  just worry about being consistent with your own code.

Comment: Also note that if you want to write something like a `where` block from Haskell in Lisp, you can easily do so with a so that you could write `(value-of <form> (where <bindings>))` and have it macroexpand to `(let <bindings> <form>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know if it's a difference of preference between:

```lisp
(defun f (x)
  (let* ((x 4) (y (1+ x)))
    (flet ((g (x) (+ 2 x)))         
       (g y))))
```

and

```
(defun f (x)
  (flet ((g (x) (+ 2 x)))         
    (let* ((x 4) (y (1+ x)))
       (g y))))
```

?

It really doesn't matter which order you put `flet`/`labels` and `let`/`let*` in this case. It will produce the same result and your CL implementation might optimize your code such that the result would be the same anyway.

In a LISP-1 you would have put it in the same `let` and then the question would be if you should put the lambda first or last. Seems like taste to me.

The only case where there is a difference is when you are making calculations that are free variables in your function. Like this:

```
(defun f (x)
  (let ((y (1+ x)))
    (flet ((g (x) (+ 2 x y))) ; y is free, made in the let*        
       (g x))))

(f 5) ; ==> 13
```

Switching order is now impossible without moving logic since the function uses a free variable. You could put the `let` inside the definition of `g` like this:

```
(defun f (x)
  (flet ((g (z) ; renamed to not shadow original x
           (let* ((y (1+ x)))
             (+ 2 z y)))         
    (g x))))
```

But imagine you used it with `mapcar`, `reduce` or recursion. Then it would have done the calculation for every iteration instead of once before the call. These are the cases that really matter.